# What do these Google Play Buildbox settings mean?

Tags: google-play

I am using Buildbox to design my first game to put on Google Play store, however I am having some issues. The game is finalized now. But I have a few questions.
The settings in Buildbox ask for my

- Bundle ID
- Name on Device
- Review Link
- Leaderboard ID
- Share Message
- License Key
- Google Play ID
- Version Code

Where do I find some of this information? Also is the share message just what I want to have said when the player shares my game?

Comment: Some of them seem to be [documented here](https://www.buildbox.com/android-upload-guide/).

Comment: thank you for your help.I was able to finish it up from there

Comment: Cool! :) Could you post what you found as an answer? Even if there's some point you're unsure about, it would help future searchers. (Answering your own questions is totally fine.)

Answer (score 2):

You make up most of this information, and the rest of it is supplied to you when you signed up for your relevant store publishing account. It's all documented in the [manual](https://www.buildbox.com/manual/):

> - Bundle ID: A unique identifier that gets embedded into the app and must be unique within a single app store. Usually in the form of
>     com.short-company-name.short-game-name.
> - Name on Device: a short name that will be displayed on the device, once the game is installed. This will appear under the game icon. If
>     the this is too long to display, the device will usually abbreviate
>     the middle of it by using ".."
> - Review Link: link within the app store that will take ther player to a page on the app store where your game can be reviewed.
> - Leaderboard ID: the code-name of the leaderboard. This is what you setup in Apple's Itunes Connect so the game can use it.
> - Share Message: the message to show to the user when prompting to share the game. If you want to show the players' score in this message
>     you can insert the special tag "[[SCORE]]" into your text. If you want
>     this message to be useful, you will need to put in a link. If you are
>     pushing to multiple platforms, you may want to make this link go to a
>     web pages instead of an app store (perhaps their friend has a
>     different kind of device).
> - Licence Key: Google play only – signing key from the game on Google Play.
> - Google Play ID: If using Google Game Services (leaderboard) then you grab the ID from setting the game up for Google Game Services.

Some of this information is optional, so if you don't have a clue what you should be using (for example, for the leaderboard ID), it's probably because your game does not make use of that feature and you can omit the data.

Your speculation about the use of the share message is correct.

Comment: Do note that the example of `com.short-company-name.short-game-name` is just an example. If you don't own `short-company-name.com` then you shouldn't use it as a bundle ID.  There is nothing wrong with `user.username.game`. For example, when I worked for a company, TPM that owned tpm.com we would sign our apps with `com.tpm.appname` but now that I'm an individual doing my own development and do not own `draco18s.com` I shouldn't use `com.draco18s.appname` as a bundle ID. I could own it (it is available), but I do not.